# Serving polymer bundles based on user-agent using Nginx

Tags: nginx, polymer

What is the possible way for serving Polymer bundles based on user agent?

1. ES-5 bundled (For IE only)
2. ES-6 bundled (For Chrome & Firefox)

I am using NGINX web server and here is my Nginx config file partial code.

```
map $http_user_agent $version {
    ~(MSIE|Edge|Trident) es5;
    default es6;
}

location /cdn {
    proxy_pass  http://my_appname/$version;
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not seems to work. if someone has one any alternate solution please share.

Comment: I would suggest to narrow down that question, how to detect user-agent via nginx and serve different resources based on that (there are nothing special about Polymer in that case).

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you use [PRPL Server](https://github.com/Polymer/prpl-server-node) which is doing exactly that. It will deliver es5 or es6 to your client depending on it´s capabilities.